# Amending a claim in a reissue patent application

Tags: claims, recapture, reissue

I introduced a claim limitation during patent prosecution to overcome prior art.

I would like to **partially** cancel this claim limitation in a reissue patent application.

Will the recapture doctrine still apply and prevent me from even **partially cancelling** the claim limitation?

Answer (score 1):

There is a section of the Manual of Patent Examining Procedure (MPEP) that covers this.

> **[1412.02   Recapture of Canceled Subject Matter](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1412.html)**
>
> A reissue will *not* be granted to "recapture" claimed subject matter which was surrendered in an application to obtain the original patent.

It does go on to list a three-part test to see if this applies. It may be possible to add a claim that broadens or removes the limitation in question as long as there is some other significant narrowing in another aspect.